# Intergral over Haar random unitary

Tags: haar-measure

Given matrices $A_i$, and map $F(X)=A_nXA_{n-1}\cdots A_1$.
How to compute
$$\int_U F(U)\otimes F(U)^{*} dU$$
where $X^*$ denotes the complex conjugate transpose and $dU$ denotes the Haar measure.

Answer (score 2):

This is a multinomial in the matrix elements of $U$; the general formula for the integral over the unitary group is given by [Weingarten calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weingarten_function); there is also a Mathematica package, [IntHaar](http://reu.dimacs.rutgers.edu/%7Ejkim/inthaar.pdf); all of this makes for a tedious computation if you seek exact expressions; if the dimensionality $N$ of the matrices is large, you can find simpler expressions by a [diagrammatic pertubation expansion](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9604059).